# Constructing geodesic parallel coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

Geodesic parallel coordinates for a surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are orthogonal coordinates such that $u$-curves are unit-speed geodesics and the $v$-curves cut segements of equal length from all the $u$-curves, so they are parallel curves at constant distance from each other. The first fundamental form is given by $$E = 1 \quad F = 0 \quad G=a^2 $$

How do we construct geodesic parallel coordinates locally at a point  $p \in S$? I don't really understand this construction from the definition given. Can someone give an example of such parameterization or a drawing to visualize it? Thanks.

Comment: Your notation $G=a^2$ suggests strongly that $G$ is constant, but that can only happen on a flat surface.

Comment: $G$ is not constant. In this case we have $K = -a_{uu}/a$, where $a_{uu}$ is the second order partial in $u$. Sorry about the notation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To construct geodesic parallel coordinates locally start with any regular curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and  let the $u$-curves $v\equiv t$ be the unit speed geodesics crossing $\gamma$ orthogonally at $\gamma(t)$.

For example starting   with the curve  $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ on the unit sphere $S^2$ you get spherical coordinates $$x(u,v)=(\cos u\cdot\cos v,\cos u \cdot\sin v, \sin u)$$

Thus  $x(u,v)$ is the point you reach if you start at $p=(1,0,0)$ and travel with unit speed first eastwards  along the equator  for time $v$ and then nortwards for  time $u$ (or in the corresponding opposite directions if $u$ or $v$ are negative).

Comment: But this doesn't necessarily give $G=\text{constant}$. In particular, in the case of your example, it certainly is not.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I assumed that $G$ is not necesarrily constant.

Comment: Well, in fact, the OP's notation suggests that $G$ should be constant, but that can only happen in the case of zero curvature, so the original statement is misleading indeed.